# URLStreamHandler is a restricted class

Tags: java, google-app-engine, http, servlets

I'm getting this error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.net.URLStreamHandler is a restricted class. Please see the Google  App Engine developer's guide for more details.
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.reject(Runtime.java:51)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.protocol.javascript.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:50)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.<clinit>(WebClient.java:144)
```

When running my GAE app, the error is within this code block:

```
    // Setup the headless browser
    webClient = new WebClient();
    webClient.setWebConnection(new UrlFetchWebConnection(webClient));
```

My app is configured with:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.htmlunit</groupId>
    <artifactId>htmlunit</artifactId>
    <version>2.13-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

I believe the `HTMLUnit` had a patch to allow it to work in the GAE environment, what could I be missing?

Comment: The exception is pretty clear to me. You can't use java.net.URLStreamHandler and HTMLUnit is using it. You should isolate the test from the GAE environment.

Comment: Because of URLStreamHandler is in whitelist i think https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/jrewhitelist

Comment: @DiogoSantana I was able to make it work with 2.13-SNAPSHOT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like I forgot to do a 'mvn clean' since I used an earlier version of HtmlUnit, the artifact was still there.

Now it works!

Comment: Great! I was gladdy to help.